# Oracle SQL If statement using select to compare

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to compare a number which I need to retrieve from the table to execute a trigger.

```
IF (Select *my table* from *column* where *condition*) < 1
then (something)
else (something)
```

but when it compile, I get the following error.

Error(2,8): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null others       avg    count current exists max min prior sql stddev sum variance    execute forall merge time timestamp interval date          pipe

Am I wrong to use select to retrieve the amount to do the check? Please advise.

Comment: read up on pl-sql if you want to do this on dbms side, otherwise make the logic in your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
number cnt := 0;
Select count(*) into val from mytable where *condition*;
if val > 0 then
(something)
else 
 (something)
end if;
```

This is the kind of logic needed.